# Python nested dict -- add value by key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've created a dict like this:

```
date1, date2 = '2018-06-06','2018-06-07'
json_first = {
    "c1": { date1 : {'title':'t1','link': 'l1','summary': 's1'}},
    "c2": { date2 : {'title':'t2','link': 'l2','summary': 's2'}}
}
```

I'm trying to progressively add more dates for each key (c1, c2) and then later retrieve it by the date. Tried using append and extend, as some other SO posts suggested, but with no luck.

```
 json_first['c1'].append({'2018-06-08': {'title':'t3','link': 'l3','summary': 's3'}})
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Am sure am missing the fundamental way to build a dict. How can we add more values to the dict by the key? I need to later access the dict by the date. Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to add a key/value to a dict, it's just `dict_name[key] = value` e.g. `json_first['c1']['2018-06-08'] = {'title':'t3','link': 'l3','summary': 's3'}`. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: looks like you need `update` method of the dict `json_first['c1'].update({'2018-06-08': {'title':'t3','link': 'l3','summary': 's3'}})`

Comment: I've removed `json` from the tags and the question because it's not at all relevant.

Comment: @BearBrown that works beautifully as well. this can help update the key later as well. cheers.

Comment: [Add new keys to a dictionary?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1024847)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_first["c1"]` is a dict like any other, so you add new key-value pairs to it with indexed assignment.

```
>>> date1, date2 = '2018-06-06','2018-06-07'
>>> json_first = {
...     "c1": { date1 : {'title':'t1','link': 'l1','summary': 's1'}},
...     "c2": { date2 : {'title':'t2','link': 'l2','summary': 's2'}}
... }
>>> json_first["c1"]['2018-06-08'] = {'title':'t3','link': 'l3','summary': 's3'}
>>> json_first
{'c1': {'2018-06-06': {'title': 't1', 'link': 'l1', 'summary': 's1'}, '2018-06-08': {'title': 't3', 'link': 'l3', 'summary': 's3'}}, 'c2': {'2018-06-07': {'title': 't2', 'link': 'l2', 'summary': 's2'}}}
```

Comment: what if I have to add a new title, link and summary to the same date like in 'c1': {'2018-06-06': {'title': 't1', 'link': 'l1', 'summary': 's1'}, {'title': 't11', 'link': 'l11', 'summary': 's11'}}

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. `{'2018-06-06': {'title': 't1', 'link': 'l1', 'summary': 's1'}, {'title': 't11', 'link': 'l11', 'summary': 's11'}}` isn't valid Python syntax, for the same reason that `{1: 2, 3}` isn't.

Comment: Sorry. Meant more like {1: {2,3}}. I'm adding multiple tuples (title, link, summary) for the same date to retrieve it later by the key ['c1']['2018-06-06'].

Comment: Perhaps then you would initially create a list, like `json_first["c1"]['2018-06-08'] = []`, and then append to it later, like `json_first["c1"]['2018-06-08'].append({'title':'t3','link': 'l3','summary': 's3'})`.

Comment: Perfect Kevin. Thanks.